# GetTextMetrics returning different maximum and average character width for Courier New

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, font-size, c++builder-6

I'm maintaining an application using Borland C++ Builder 6 running on Windows 7.

The application is incorrectly drawing text using font Courier New because each letter is being slighty cut off. The issue is when calling the method GetTextMetrics because it is filling the TEXTMETICS struct with differing tmAveCharWidth and tmMaxCharWidth values. The application then uses tmAveCharWidth to calculate character width with is wrong because that value it can be less than tmMaxCharWidth. That issue I will be fixing.

I courious why GetTextMetrics is returning differing tmAveCharWidth and tmMaxCharWidth values for Courier New? My understanding was that Courier New is a monospaced font and that tmAveCharWidth and tmMaxCharWidth should be the same. I tested with other monospaced fonts that that assumption is correct.

This is the section of code with the issue:

```
hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lpInstData->lf);

hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
hFontOld = SelectObject(hDC, hFont);


GetTextMetrics(hDC, &tm);
lpInstData->nCharHeight = tm.tmHeight;
lpInstData->nCharWidth = tm.tmAveCharWidth; <--- Should be using tmMaxCharWidth
```

Here is the code running when I selected size 12 Courier New.

[Parameter passed to CreateFontIndirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUyqO.png)

[TEXTMETRICS structure returned from GetTextMetrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbh5v.png)

Comment: I expect this is ClearType at work. The character width is X, the maximum width of the drawn string takes into account ClearType and returns Y. (Note that the ClearType drawing changes subtly depending on the string)

Comment: This is surely caused by TrueType hinting, it stretches the letter shape to fit the pixel grid.  I don't know how to turn it off in native code or if it is even an option, I only know of Graphics::SetTextRenderingHint().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this was indeed ClearType at work (thanks Deanna). Turning off ClearType corrects the display issue without changing any code, although I still need to correct how the application works with ClearType.

I also found the issue was not present on Windows XP because ClearType is turned off by default, whereas in Windows 7 (and Vista) it is turned on by default.